# PointDNS - "Name is managed by another account" on Heroku App

Tags: heroku, dns, pointdns

I'm trying to add a domain at one of my heroku apps.
I just added a custom domain in the app, but when I open PointDNS(DNS host recommended by heroku), my domain isn't listed there.

It shows the message `You haven't added any domains yet. Go ahead, and add your first domain.`

Then, when I try to **add** the domain name, it says `Name is managed by another account`.

I checked all my other apps, and no one have this domain registered. I've also tried the command `heroku domains -a my-app` and it correctly shows me the registered domain.

Summarize: I can't manage a domain in PointDNS due to the error `Name is managed by another account`, but there is no another account with this same domain. What could the problem be?

Comment: i would suggest you to use other services like DNSimple or Cloudflare as it is such a pain to deal with poitnDNS

Comment: Are those services available in heroku?

Comment: No third party application, but integration is straight forward. I am suggesting you as one of my sites was down recently and pointDNS was not able to resolve in a week. Although I have used pointDNS service over 3 years

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't solve the problem with PointDNS support, I've decided to transfer my website onto another domain registrar. That's it.